# Android project, jar mismatch issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am developing Android Application but when I imported to project at another computer after installing sdk and eclipse etc, I am getting Path:

```
D:\AndroidDevelopment\project_name\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-12-13 23:53:54 - project_name]    Length: 758727
[2014-12-13 23:53:54 - project_name]    SHA-1: efec67655f6db90757faa37201efcee2a9ec3507
[2014-12-13 23:53:54 - project_name] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

I have `android-support-v7-appcompat library` installed and its copy at workspace. 
I am not sure why I am getting error about `android-support-v4.jar mismatch`.

Attach is screen shot of properties of my project.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Did you try removing the copy from libs folder of the project? I faced an similar issue about mismatch too. I removed the jar from my libs folder and did a rebuild, it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the broken ..\appcompat_v7 from your libraries.
And do remove the android-support-v4.jar from libs folder of your project as it is already present in android-support-v7-appcompat

Answer (score 2):

`android-support-v4.jar` is part of the `android-support-v7-appcompat` library.

From you screenshot it seems that the `..\appcompat_v7` is broken but exists twice. So select it and press `Remove`

If the issue still exist update `..\google-play-services-lib`.

---

This is happening when 2 or more dependent projects reference 2 different versions of the same library.

### General Solution:

See what is the "problematic" library.

**Try to eliminate dublicate libraries.**

Remove that library in a way to have only one instance of it. You can reference one library to use another library.

**Try make all libraries the same.**

- Delete and re-import from the SDK all `android-support-v4.jar` if this is the case. OR
- Copy and paste one library jar to all other packages so all have the same version. It is suggested to import the last update version for that.